# How do I interpret (assert) here in c?

Tags: c, syntax

```
void (assert)(int e)
{
    assert(e);
}
```

How does it work here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void (assert)(int e)` is equivalent to `void assert(int)`

Why would you need it?

Consider the following example

```
#include<stdio.h>
void foo(int a)
{
printf("%d", a);
}
#define foo(a) {/*I do nothing*/}

int main()
{
  foo(5); // won't call `foo`
}
```

How would you make sure when you call `foo`, its the function that is called and not the macro-definition substituted at the place of call?

The solution is to put an extra parenthesis like `(foo)(5)`

Similarly `assert` is already known to be a macro. That's the reason I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

Since `assert` already is defined as a function-style macro, without the parentheses it would have been expanded *both* in the function header and in the body.

For example:

```
#define twice(x) ((x)+(x))
void twice(int i)
{
  return twice(i);
}
```

Will expand to the following, which clearly is not legal

```
void ((int i)+(int i))
{
  return ((i)+(i));
}
```

On the other hand:

```
#define twice(x) ((x)+(x))
void (twice)(int i)
{
  return twice(i);
}
```

Will expand to:

```
void (twice)(int i)
{
  return ((i)+(i));
}
```

The extra parentheses around the function name is simply ignored by the compiler.

This is a common trick often used in the source of the standard library, on in other contexts where there might be functions and macros with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

It's legal syntax, just writing it with extra parentheses.  The reason you'd do that is because `assert()` is often defined as a macro; so the above function exists to make `assert()` be a real function, probably so you can set a breakpoint in it.